# Let error AND returning/printing a "string" for scheme procedure

Tags: scheme, lisp, racket

my function checks simple values and should have output/return depending on the result. I have 2 problems:
1. when I replace the let value (-1) of runner with the expression `(randint (-5 10))`, where `randint` is another procedure that returns a random number between -5 and 10, it doesnt work

2. I want to return/print a string for the first two if statements if they are true, dont know how to do that in scheme.

Here is the code:

```
(define (check)
  (let (runner(randint -5 10)
    (cond ((and (< runner 1) (> runner -3))
           (display "yes"))
          ((and (< runner -2) (> runner -6))
           (display "no"))
          ((> runner 0)
           (display runner))))))
```

Here is the code for randint:

```
(define random
(let ((a 69069) (c 1) (m (expt 2 32)) (seed 19380110))
 (lambda new-seed
 (if (pair? new-seed)
 (set! seed (car new-seed))
 (set! seed (modulo (+ (* seed a) c) m)))
 (/ seed m))))

(define (randint . args)
 (cond ((= (length args) 1)
 (floor (* (random) (car args))))
 ((= (length args) 2)
 (+ (car args) (floor (* (random) (- (cadr args) (car args))))))
 (else (error 'randint "usage: (randint [lo] hi)"))))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apart from the syntax problems pointed by @Rptx, there's one killer bug in your code: you can't have one-armed `if`s in Racket (meaning: they *must* have a consequent and an alternative). You can either nest them, or better yet: use `cond`, which is perfect for testing multiple conditions. This should work:

```
(define (check)
  (let ((runner (randint -5 10)))
    (cond ((and (< runner 1) (> runner -3))
           "yes")
          ((and (< runner -2) (> runner -6))
           "no")
          ((> runner 0)
           runner))))
```

Use it like this:

```
(display (check))
```

Regarding the issue with `randint`: Now that you have posted the code I can confirm that the problem was in the way that you were passing the parameters. As shown above, this is the correct way:

```
(randint -5 10)
```

Comment: I modified the code, as @Rptx mentioned, I want to return not print, yes,no,runner. Sorry for the confusion, im trying to set the randint function to runner variable to reuse the result without recalling the function(to keep the same value generated). This is the error im getting                         let: bad syntax (not an identifier and expression for a binding) in: runner

Comment: @user3241846 OK, I updated my answer. It should be all right now ;)

Comment: Im getting this result #<procedure:check>, im using drracket 6.1, language: R5RS

Comment: You have to _call_ the procedure. I don't know how are you invoking it (it's not in the question), but this is working for me: `(check)` or to print it: `(display (check))`

Comment: this is embarassing, I forgot the brackets. I cant thank you enough for your patience :)

Comment: @user3241846 no problem, it was my pleasure :)

Answer (score 2):

It really hurts my eyes to see 3 expressions in a implicit begin with each their own `if` without alternative. Here is a version using `cond` (only because it's 2 terms and an alternative) Also notice that it's enough with one `<` with the bounds on each side of your variable rather than splitting it up in two with a logical `and` between.

```scm
(define (check)
  (let ((runner -1))
    (cond ((< -3 runner 1)  "yes")
          ((< -6 runner -2) "no")
          (else "runner"))))

(display (check)) ; ==> void, displays the result of check
```

Answer (score 1):

There are several mistakes in your code.

1. You are missing parens around `check`. You are currently defining check as a variable, not as a procedure.
2. You are missing a procedure to print.
3. Print and return are not the same thing. The procedure will return what the last statement
   of the body of let returns. In your case, it will return `'runner` if (> runner 0) is true, or false otherwise.
4. If you don't post the error you get when you use `randint` We can't know what is wrong.

Here is a working version of your procedure:

```
(define (check)
  (let ((runner -1))
    (if (and (< runner 1) (> runner -3)) (display "yes"))
    (if (and (< runner -2) (> runner -6)) (display "no"))
    (if (> runner 0) (car '(runner)))))
```

Comment: I understand better now. I need it to return no,yes,runner to be used by another tree building function. I still dont have a complete grasp on function as opposed to object oriented.

Comment: @Sylwester's version will return the strings. `(display "yes")` will print it to screen, but the return value is undefined. If you do something like `(define a (display "yes"))` `a` will not be assigned to "yes". It's value would be undefined, which is the actual returned value of display. You can test something like `(cons (display "yes\n") yes)` and in racket will print "yes" and on another line `'(#<void> . "yes")` Demonstrating this.